# gulp uncss function error when running

Tags: php, laravel, gulp, uncss

I am trying to use gulp uncss in my my laravel project but can’t seem to get the syntax correct. My gulp task is:

```
gulp.task('uncss', function() {
     return gulp.src('public/output/final.css')
     .pipe(uncss({
         html:['resources/views/welcome.blade.php']
        }))
        .pipe(rename({suffix: '.clean'}))
     .pipe(gulp.dest('public/css/'));
});
```

I realise this is only acting on the one page welcome.blade.php but I want to test the results first. With the above code, am I getting the following error:
`fn = function () { throw arg; };`
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this is not possible as UnCSS can't compile server side languages such as PHP